# How to swipe to same Fragment but with other data:?

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, swipe

I'm building this application where I have 2 activities. Both of them consist of 3 fragment - one for title, one for content and one for tab control. It is shown at image below.

[image: app design]

First activity serves for showing list of some data's headers (item name etc.), search, app info etc. When user presses item in list, app takes him to another activity to show him detail of chosen item. This "details" activity has 6 different content fragments and user switch between them via buttons in tab control fragment (I did switching between content fragments by showing chosen one and hiding all others - I don't know if it's right way, it's my firs app so it came to my mind at first :) ).

And what I would like to do is: When I'm in detail and I swipe left/right then I want app to take me to previous/next item's detail, to same fragment where I currently was in (so not to next content fragment, but to detail of next item in 1st activity's list).

Is this somehow possible please? Because I have totally no clue how to do it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And what I would like to do is: When I'm in detail and I swipe
>   left/rigt then I want app to take me to previous/next item's detail,
>   to same fragment where I currently was in (so not to next content
>   fragment, but to detail of next item in 1st activity's list).

If you want to swipe left-right then you would need a `ViewPager` widget. I'm not sure how should your details activity behave so I'm providing you with two options. Do you want to be able to switch to the next/previous item's details **only when a certain fragment is the one currently viewed by the user**(from the 6 content fragments, which I assume are related and show various data for a single item)? If yes then in that desired fragment you would replace the current content of the fragment(which will only act as a container) with a `ViewPager` and use nested fragments for the actual content. If the user switches to the details of a previous/next item's details and then suddenly wants to see the data for that item from one of the remaining 5 content fragments then you would need to have some updates method on them to refresh the data to show the current item(a `OnPageChangeListener` will be useful here).

Second option, is if you want to allow the user to swipe left/right from any of the 6 content fragments. If this is the case you would use the same method as above but you'll modify each of those 6 fragments.

Showing the next/previous item is easy, just get some sort of identifier of the data(a position, id), retrieve the whole used data(as in the first activity) and then cycle between it.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already trying to do that thisway: I have 1 ViewPager and 6 different types of adapter. Each to show one type of detail. And in depend of in which tab I am currently, I switch ViewPager's adapter. But now I have a different problem. When I switch adapter via viewPager.setAdapter(...) then nothing happens :/

Comment: Ok, using FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter solved the thing :)